# Form POST action wont work

Tags: php, jquery, post, methods

Why wont this work?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="searchBar" name="domain" /><input type="button" value="SEARCH" class="searchButton" id="srch" />
</form>


<? print $_POST['domain']; ?>
```

I have tried putting it into a var too. I just got an error.

Thanks

Edit:
Suggestions have been made of changing button to submit, but my jQuery bug's up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#srch').click(function(){ 
      $('#notActive').attr('id','Active'); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){

  // Hide div 2 by default
  $('#Active').hide();

  $('#srch').click(function(){ 
      $('#notActive').hide();
      $('#Active').fadeIn();
  });
});
</script>
```

I have managed to change the Button to Submit by using the action as `javascript: void(0);` for my form.

Comment: use <?php when dealing with php. <? is ambiguous and could be interpreted as xml among other things

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have `short_open_tags` enabled? If not, use `<?php ?>`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Notice: Undefined index: domain

Comment: @KaiQing I tried <php ?> and it still did not work.

Comment: @Rahul Without seeing your full code, I am going to guess that you are trying to access `$_POST['domain']` before actually submitting the form and the undefined index is a result of the script loading the first time, before submission.

Comment: `<?php print isset($_POST['domain']) ? $_POST['domain'] : ''; ?>`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That is all the main PHP code that I have done. All I am trying to do is search then click the button. and after the button is clicked the content of the search the user has typed will appear.

Comment: <?php was a general comment, not an answer to your problem. I think Oğuzhan Eroğlu got it with the submit button.

Comment: @KaiQing it messes with my JQ

Comment: Do you mean jQuery? If so I would say you should write your jquery to conform to the html and not necessarily the other way around. Perhaps you should post that code as well so we can suggest alternatives - if applicable

Comment: @KaiQing I have edited the post, please take a look.

Comment: this is contradictory to your question. You want the submit button to alter the DOM, but you also want to collect post data. You should look into $.ajax if you want something to submit without reloading the page. Otherwise, consider some post form processing variables being used to write attributes into the html on load.

Comment: @KaiQing Is it possible to help me with this please? Maybe over Team Viewer?

Comment: let's start by updating your question with the full contents of the relevant code. Your jquery is affecting elements. Let's see those.

Answer (score 2):

The form cant submit if contains no **type="submit"** input.

`<input type="button" />` cant submit form. You should add `<input type="submit" />` to form.

Comment: you can add an onsubmit="return false" to the form tag to prevent natural behavior, but that will prevent the form from posting and therefore your original problem will persist. You're altering the id attribute on submit - an effect that would be lost if you submit the post without ajax anyhow... this was meant for OP but the comment is gone

Comment: @KaiQing jQuery is even worse than my PHP, could you help me fix this problem please? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the posted variable *before* a form is submitted.

```
if (isset($_POST['domain'])) {
    // a form is submitted that contains the 'domain' parameter
    print $_POST['domain'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an action:

`<form action="index.php" method="POST">`.

Also, change your second line to this:

`<? if (isset($_POST['domain'])) echo ($_POST['domain']); ?>`

Comment: They are both in the same file. index.php

Comment: You missed  )) i think, and still not working, but thanks for your time.

Comment: This works, but the problem is I have to press enter on my keyboard then click search for it to show in my hidden div.